# undocumented esc/pos commands, what do they do?

Tags: escpos

I have been capturing some data from an Epson TM-T88V esc/pos printer to see how they are doing things in the windows driver.  I have encountered a few undocumented commands.  Does anyone know what these commands do?

I have checked the various Application Programming guides, the online ESC/POS Command Reference for TM Printers, and Googled the heck out of the commands and have not been able to find any references.

Command 1:

```
[Format]
ASCII   ESC   (     s     pL    pH    d1    d2    d3    d4
Hex     1b    28    73    04    00    31    41    ??    ??          
Decimal 27    40    114   4     0     40    73    ??    ?? 

[Response]
7b 20 41 35 33 35 34 34 44 34 45 34 44 34 41 34 42 35 30 00

[Notes]
The Response looks like a  0x7b header-null block.
```

Command 2:

```
[Format]

ASCII   ESC   (     J     pL    pH    d1    d2              
Hex     1d    28    4a    02    00    ??    00          
Decimal 29    40    74    2     0     ?     0       

[Response]
There seems to be no response to this command.
```

Command 3:
ESC I n where n = 113, 114

```
[Name] Transmit printer ID
[Format]
ASCII   GS    I     n
Hex     1D    49    n
Decimal 29    73    n

[Response] 0x5f header-null block 
[notes] The GS I command itself is document, but the command with n = 113 (0x71) or 114 (0x72) is not.
```